# Where is the Mythbuntu control center diskless server option

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv, ltsp

Mythbuntu's control center used to have an option to setup a diskless server. I've got it going manually but I wanted to know;

Is the option to make diskless systems coming back to mythbuntu-control-center?

Where can I download the development release of mythbuntu-control-center to help make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diskless option in mythbuntu-control-centre (MCC) didn't make the transition when MCC was rewritten to allow plugins. (Previously all functionality was written in the MCC code) The main developer behind the diskless functionality left the team to go to University, and none of the other developers use that functionality so it has not been ported to the new MCC yet. I've seen a few people offer to port the code in the past, but none have actually done it.